# How to fix 'TypeError - nil is not a symbol nor a string:'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

I have  two actions `form_one` and `form_two`. One is alias to the other.

FormsController

```
def form_one
  @selected_tab = { form_type => :selected }
end

alias :form_two :form_one

private

def form_type
  @form_type = params[:form_type]
end
```

I have declared it's 'get' route. It displays the form. I have written `update` action in a module and included the module in the `FormsController`. Update route is also declared. I have two tabs of same actions. When one tab is selected from view, the `form_type` of that form is sent to the controller private method `form_type`.

views/tabs:

```
%span
  = link_to 'Form_one' form_one_path(form_type: :form_one)
%span    
  = link_to 'Form_two' form_two_path(form_type: :form_two)
```

form_partial:

```
= form_for @form_type, url: form_path(@resource), method: :patch, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

While displaying the forms, the params are passed correctly, but while updating, the params are passed as `nil`.

I passed the params as `form_type` to the paths, but it still gives the same error. If I add an `or` condition in `form_type` method like this:

```
@form_type = params[:form_type] || 'form_one'
```

it then just updates the attributes of `form_one`. And if the condition is removed, `@form_type` is `nil` because the params are `nil`.

When I update the attributes of a specific form, they should get updated. But here, the params are passed as `nil` while updating. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_type` Should be passed either with `routes` or in `hidden field`

As following -

```
 = form_for @form_type, url: form_path(@resource, form_type: params[:action]), method: :patch, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|

  =# hidden_field_tag :form_type, params[:action]
```

In this way you will be able to get value for `params[:form_type]` at update action

Comment: I have a common partial for both the forms. So passing `form_type: 'form_one'` specific will update only one form's attributes. I want update action to work for both forms

Comment: Hi @Neha I understand that, in that case you can always get `params[:action]` which will be equivalent to current action name.

Comment: Are you using these common partial in `form_one` or `form_two` ? if it's so then you will get value in `params[:action]` which in equivalent to current action. in other case you must pass anyhow in hidden field for which action form to be submitted. hope it's make sense. let me know for further guidance as well.

Comment: thanks for the solution. The `=# hidden_field_tag :form_type, params[:action]` worked. Thanks alot

Comment: @Neha Glad to know that, feel free to upvote answer for future SO searchers.